# Creating and using of procname.so

Tags: python, import, makefile

I would like to edit the process name of my python scripts by the use of http://code.google.com/p/procname/

I downloaded the source file of procname, extracted the content into my script directory and changed the makefile to:

```
PYTHON?=python3
TESTFLAGS=-p -v
TESTOPTS=
SETUPFLAGS=
GCC=gcc
VER=3.1
DESTDIR=.
```

Then I did `make` and `procname.so` was created in the same directory where my script is.
In the script I added `import procname` and tried to edit the process name by `procname.setprocname('test_name.py')`.

Now i get an error:

```
import procname  
ImportError: /path/to/script_directory/procname.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `procname` extension module does not work in Python 3.  `procnamemodule.c` uses `Py_InitModule3`, which no longer exists in Python 3.

Comment: Sorry, no.  The psutil package lets you retrieve the name of a process, and I was hopeful it would allow you to set it, but apparently it does not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information! Hope there will be "soon" a solution to this!